# Fetch the value from the object of objects in a React Functional component JS object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following object in React JavaScript,

```
const obj = {
    "time": 1639700933808,
    "lastChanges": [
        [
            {
                "op": "add",
                "path": "nodes.mpcWlu3JhV.data.nodes.1",
                "value": "4aI6ltJzAw"
            },
            {
                "op": "add",
                "path": "nodes.4aI6ltJzAw",
                "value": {
                    "id": "4aI6ltJzAw",
                    "data": {
                        "name": "DdLookup",
                        "displayName": "Lookup",
                        "props": {
                            "name": "",
                            "code": ""
                        },
                        "custom": {},
                        "parent": "mpcWlu3JhV",
                        "isCanvas": false,
                        "hidden": false,
                        "nodes": [],
                        "linkedNodes": {}
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "op": "add"

            },
            {
                "op": "replace"
            },
            {
                "op": "add"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "op": "replace"
            },
            {
                "op": "add"
            }
        ]
    ],
    "nodes": {
        "ROOT": {
            "type": {
                "resolvedName": "Flex"
            },
            "isCanvas": false,
            "props": {
                "className": "oDWyIL2AvKKc6Taj-CEQt"
            },
            "displayName": "Flex",
            "custom": {},
            "hidden": false,
            "nodes": [
                "LFpcm_Fewn"
            ],
            "linkedNodes": {}
        },
        "LFpcm_Fewn": {
            "type": {
                "resolvedName": "FormRoot"
            },
            "isCanvas": true,
            "props": {
                "name": "123",
                "code": "DEV_123"
            },
            "displayName": "Form",
            "custom": {},
            "parent": "ROOT",
            "hidden": false,
            "nodes": [],
            "linkedNodes": {
                "form-body": "mpcWlu3JhV"
            }
        },
        "mpcWlu3JhV": {
            "type": "div",
            "isCanvas": true,
            "props": {
                "className": "_3Op7nHDBF8ya__B1tPDfL_ e1nzbV5Ci4vpgTdE1tSJO FormBodyContainer",
                "inGridContainer": false,
                "formOrderId": 0
            },
            "displayName": "div",
            "custom": {
                "target": "FormBody"
            },
            "parent": "LFpcm_Fewn",
            "hidden": false,
            "nodes": [
                "ybX-r34-ij",
                "4aI6ltJzAw"
            ],
            "linkedNodes": {}
        },
        "ybX-r34-ij": {
            "type": {
                "resolvedName": "DdTextBox"
            },
            "isCanvas": false,
            "props": {
                "name": "trt",
                "code": "DEV_TRT"
            },
            "displayName": "Text box",
            "custom": {},
            "parent": "mpcWlu3JhV",
            "hidden": false,
            "nodes": [],
            "linkedNodes": {}
        },
        "4aI6ltJzAw": {
            "type": {
                "resolvedName": "DdLookup"
            },
            "isCanvas": false,
            "props": {
                "name": "",
                "code": ""
            },
            "displayName": "Lookup",
            "custom": {},
            "parent": "mpcWlu3JhV",
            "hidden": false,
            "nodes": [],
            "linkedNodes": {}
        }
    }
};
```

I am trying to iterate through the `nodes` object, I want to find the `code` property under the props when the `displayName` is `Form`. How should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can map through the object values:

```
 const nodeValues = Object.values(obj.nodes);  // get the nodes values 
     
 const allCodes = nodeValues.map(o => {
   if(o.displayName == "Form")  // check if displayName is Form
       return {
            code: o.props.code,
            linkedNodes: o.props.linkedNodes
       }    // Get the code or return an object if you need other values
}).filter(v => v)
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar approach to the answer of @subodhkalika only this one has one iteration rather than use map then filter.

```
const codes = [];
Object.values(obj.nodes).forEach(node => {
    if(node.displayName === "Form" && node.props?.code) {
      push(node.props.code);
    }
});
```